# WSO2 EI: is there a way to add value to array in JSON using enrich mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2EI 6.4.0 and working in scenario where I have below json message

```
{
    "id": "ede05f60-fa26-4d03-b231-54d36d589bbb",
    "name": "TestAPIName",
    "description": "TestAPIName description",
    "context": "/TestAPIName",
    "version": "v1",
    "provider": "example@example.com",
    "status": "PUBLISHED",
    "sequences": [],
    "corsConfiguration": {
        "corsConfigurationEnabled": false,
        "accessControlAllowOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "accessControlAllowCredentials": false,
        "accessControlAllowHeaders": [
            "authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Content-Type",
            "SOAPAction"
        ],
        "accessControlAllowMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "PATCH",
            "OPTIONS"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I have value of sequence in property mediator

```
<property expression="get-property('sequenceName')" name="seqName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

I want to add this value of seqName into the above json message in sequences array. So the output should be like below

```
{
    "id": "ede05f60-fa26-4d03-b231-54d36d589bbb",
    "name": "TestAPIName",
    "description": "TestAPIName description",
    "context": "/TestAPIName",
    "version": "v1",
    "provider": "example@example.com",
    "status": "PUBLISHED",
    "sequences": [{"name":"<valuefrompropertymediator>","type": "in"},{"name":"log_out_message","type": "out"}],
    "corsConfiguration": {
        "corsConfigurationEnabled": false,
        "accessControlAllowOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "accessControlAllowCredentials": false,
        "accessControlAllowHeaders": [
            "authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Content-Type",
            "SOAPAction"
        ],
        "accessControlAllowMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "PATCH",
            "OPTIONS"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use enrich here, or how to proceed in this. The other objects and array will be as it is. Only the sequences needs to be updated.

Thanks

Comment: JSON support for the Enrich mediator is introduced in later EI versions. 
If possible could you please test this in EI 6.6.0 

www. lahirumadushankablog.wordpress.com/2018/12/12/enriching-json-payloads-in-wso2-ei

Else, you can convert the inserting payload to XML and enrich using custom XAPTH expression

Comment: I got this working using script mediator.

Comment: great! but please note that script mediator costs you some performance.  It is advised to use script mediator only when the transformation is impossible with other mediators.